# php POST and ECHO on three pages

Tags: php

I want to echo my result from first page on the second page and then get the same ruslt from the second page and echo it on the third page

page 1:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

page2:

```
echo $_POST['code'];
```

What should I add in my second page and to write in the thrid one?

Comment: Use [sessions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

page 1:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="age" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

page 3:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
echo $_SESSION['name'].'<br />';
echo $_SESSION['age'].'<br />';
?>
```

Comment: I'd give *you* an A on this assigment, but expel user1823527 for getting someone else to do his homework for him.

Answer (score 1):

You have differents options

In the first page, the input text must has the same name as the second page.

page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="code" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The second page can has another form with hidden input

page2.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['code'];
?>
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="echo $_POST['code']" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['code'];
?>
```

OR, if you make it with a link
page2.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['code'];
echo "<a href='page3.php?code=" .$_POST['code']. "'>LINK TO 3rd PAGE</a>";
?>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['code'];
?>
```